Why is it simpler to express the cut-elimination rule in general deductive systems than strictly formal systems?
This article says:

Depending on the strength of the metalanguage used to define the
judgments and steps, simply having a deductive system does not in
itself necessarily yield an effective procedure for enumerating valid
proof trees and theorems. Deductive systems which do yield such an
enumeration are sometimes referred to as formal systems. For example,
Gödel’s incompleteness theorems are statements about formal systems in
this sense. It is worth keeping in mind that more general deductive
systems are considered in proof theory and type theory, typically
because by side-stepping these coding issues one can give a simpler
account of computational phenomena such as cut-elimination.

Can anyone explain why or provide an example for how “general deductive systems” are able to “side-step” the “coding issues” of strictly formal systems which allows them to give a “simpler account” of the cut-elimination rule?

It might be better to ask this in math se or phil se. I think I might have an vague idea of what they mean, but I’ve never seen a proof of cut elimination in either “general deductive systems” or “formal systems” so I can’t give examples. I’m guessing that by coding issues they just mean formalizing the proofs via Gödel encodings and having to deal with the heavily computational and maybe notationally messy aspects of it.
